# Building menu of files in folder hierarchy

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a folder, and in that folder are files and other folders, with files and folders in it, etc. Now what I am trying to do is make a drop down menu and add each filename to the menu, and if it is a folder it creates a submenu and adds the filesname in that folder to that menu, etc. I kind of have some (incomplete) code:

```
def TemplatesSetup(self):

  # add templates menu
  template_menu = self.menubar.addMenu('&Templates')

  #temp = template_menu.addMenu()

  # check if templates folder exists
  if os.path.exists('templates/') is False:
    temp = QAction('Can not find templates folder...', self)
    temp.setDisabled (1)
    template_menu.addAction(temp)
    return

  for fulldir, folder, filename in os.walk('templates'):

    for f in filename:
      template_menu.addAction(QAction(f, self))
```

but I am still not sure how the best way to go about this would be. Any ideas?

Comment: Please make your title somewhat descriptive of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a full example for you.

```
import sys
import os
import os.path

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        template_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&Templates')
        menus = {'templates': template_menu}

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('templates'):
            current = menus[dirpath]
            for dn in dirnames:
                menus[os.path.join(dirpath, dn)] = current.addMenu(dn)
            for fn in filenames:
                current.addAction(fn)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @user2638731 I thought I'd get away with not using `os.path.join`. Apparently not. Answer updated.